# Mysql group by date and count query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table as below :-
[image]

With help of MySql query, I want result as below:

```
date        total    read    unread
2018-01-31   8        4        4
2018-02-01   2        2        0
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) as total,
SUM(CASE WHEN read = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as read
SUM(CASE WHEN read = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as unread
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: On using this query "SELECT `id`,`date`, COUNT(*) as totalcnt,
SUM(`read`) as readcnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN `read` = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as unreadcnt
FROM email_notifications
GROUP BY `date`" 1064 error is coming

Comment: @Tarika: dear, remove id field. Because it doesn't present in group by

Comment: Or you can use aggregate function on `id` as `MAX(id) as id`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as unreadcnt FROM email_notifications GROUP BY `date`,`id` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3

Comment: @Tarika:you have missed END statement after ELSE 0

Comment: @Tarika: Have a nice day. If you want accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use case for aggregate the filtered  value for read

```
select date
, count(*), sum(case when  read=1 then 1 else 0 end )  as read
, sum(case when  read=0 then 1 else 0 end )  as unread
from my_table 
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This** we don't need case in the `read` column as `1` means `read` so we simply `sum` the value. It will help in the performance if we are dealing with the huge data:

```
SELECT date, 
    COUNT(*) as total,
    SUM(read) as read --Case not needed here
    SUM(CASE WHEN read = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) as unread
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group rows by date using `group by`, then you can use `count` to count the total number of rows within each date group (= total column).
In order to obtain the number of read and unread, you can `sum` read and unread value

```
        SELECT date
             , COUNT(*) AS total
             , SUM(READ) AS READ
             , SUM(CASE WHEN READ = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unread
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY date
```